# Apps script : How do I return data filtered by month year?

Tags: google-apps-script, datefilter

I need to get the data filtered by month and year with dates in column A.
I tried something like this, but have a problem with the date formatting

```
function testMonthYear() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  Logger.log("data : " + JSON.stringify(data) +" "  + data.length)
  
  var filteredData = data.filter(function(r) {return Utilities.formatDate(r[0],"GMT+2",'MMMMyyyy' ==  "December2021")});
  
  Logger.log("filteredData : " + filteredData + "  "  + filteredData.length )  

}
```

Here's a simple test sheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P58YMZZ5VrVCrTR8huhhhnmsOMZvKnzRqEqua2dICpo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function(r) {return Utilities.formatDate(r[0],"GMT+2",'MMMMyyyy' ==  "December2021")});
```

#### To:

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function (r) { return Utilities.formatDate(r[0], "GMT+2", 'MMMMyyyy') == "December2021" });
```

or

```
var filteredData = data.filter(r => Utilities.formatDate(r[0], "GMT+2", 'MMMMyyyy') == "December2021");
```

- `Utilities.formatDate(r[0],"GMT+2",'MMMMyyyy' ==  "December2021")` is modified to `Utilities.formatDate(r[0], "GMT+2", 'MMMMyyyy') == "December2021"`.

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)